# cURL GET request returns result on local, but on production returns null?

Tags: php, post, curl

I have a problem, which I find difficult to debug. For my project, I use cURL to make GET request to public API. On localhost I receive result, but when I publish to production, the result is "null". One thing to notice is that my project doesn't have SSL certificate, but the public API I connect to - has. I am not sure if this makes any difference, but I am mentioning it anyway.

Here is example of my request:

```
public function latestArticles($count) {

    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://public-api.com/LatestResults?count=' . $count);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    if($output === false)
    {
        echo "Error Number:".curl_errno($ch)."<br>";
        echo "Error String:".curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;

}
```

Comment: Is curl installed on your production web server? I would wager it's not.

Comment: maybe some firewall issue?

Comment: Try curling something else out.

Comment: for debugging, what happens if you do: `$hc=new hhb_curl();$hc->_setComfortableOptions();$hc->exec('http://public-api.com/LatestResults?count=' . $count); var_dump($hc->getStdErr());` , both on localhost and on the remote machine? with the code from https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the web server at the moment and I can't tell is the cURL installed. I have to fix this ASAP, so if I use Guzzle instead (download it with composer to my project), is it going to work on production environment without additional installations?

Comment: yeah probably. i heard guzzle will fallback to http streams, and eventually to sockets, if curl is not installed